# 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-re

Can anyone can help me figure out this problem?

Code

```
import re
import time 
import requests
import pandas as pd 
from retrying import retry
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

start = time.clock()

plist=[]
for i in range(1,101):
    j=44*(i-1)
    plist.append(j)
    
listno=plist
datamsp=pd.DataFrame(columns=[])

while True:
    @retry(stop_max_attempt_number=8)
    def network_programming(num):
        url='https://s.taobao.com/search?q=沙发&type=p&tmhkh5=&spm=a21wu.241046-global.a2227oh.d100&from=sea_1_suggest&catId=100&bcoffset=3&ntoffset=3&p4ppushleft=1%2C48&s='+str(num)
        web=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
        web=encoding ='utf-8'
        return web
    
    def multithreading():
        number=listno
        event=[]
    
    
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)as executor:
            for result in executor.map (network_programming ,number,chunksize=10):
                event.append(result)
        return event 
    
    headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}
    listpg=[]
    event= multithreading()
    for i in event:
        json=re.findall('"auctions":(.*?),"recommendAuctions"',i.text)
        if len(json):
            table=pd.read_json(json[0])
            datamsp=pd.concat([datamsp,table],axis=0,ignore_index=True)
            
            pg=findall('"pageNum":(.*?),"p4pbottom_up"',i.text[0])
            listpg.append(pg)
            
    lists=[]
    for a in listpg:
        b=44*(int(a)-1)
        lists.append(b)
        
    listn=listno
    listno=[]
    for p in listn:
        listno.append(p)
        
    if len(listno)==0:
        break
        
datamsp.to_excel('datamsp.xls',index=False)

end=time.clock()
print("time cost:",end-start,'s')
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-35c03bdc4fc9> in <module>
     38     event= multithreading()
     39     for i in event:
---> 40         json=re.findall('"auctions":(.*?),"recommendAuctions"',i.text)
     41         if len(json):
     42             table=pd.read_json(json[0])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What does the error message tell you about the line in question?

Answer (score 3):

In `for i in event` block, `i` is already a string. Change line 40 to `json = re.findall('"auctions:(.*?),"recommendAuctions"', i)`